# How to Mount a different Drive than local C:/ for Clickhouse?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, drive, clickhouse

I am running clickhouse in wsl windows 10. It runs fine at the moment. I want to make sure to drive all storage of data to a different drive other than the C:/ drive, specifically my E:/ drive. I imagine one could create a database there but I am unsure how to go about it. Documentation does not seem clear on this.

Comment: All drives are automatically mounted in `/mnt` directory by default.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](https://www.scivision.dev/mount-usb-drives-windows-subsystem-for-linux/), you can just do the this:

Create the directory you want the drive to be mounted to:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/e
```

And mount it using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs e: /mnt/e
```

You can use any directory you want for this or any drive(even network drives) for this(make sure to put the right directory drive letter).